# ngAnimate 1.5.6 not adding enter and leave classes to ng-view

Tags: angularjs

Using Angular and angular-animate, both are 1.5.6

I am not having success with `ngAnimate`. From what I can tell, the classes `ng-enter` and `ng-leave` are not being added to `<div class="col-xs-12 view-animation" ng-view></div>`. What am I doing wrong?

index.html:

```
  <body ng-app="gulpNewy">
    <div id="sidebar-back-drop"></div>
    <div class="row">
      <div id="sidebar-bar-static">
        <a href="#home" class="button-side btn btn-block btn-inverse">Home</a>
        <a href="#examples" class="button-side btn btn-block btn-inverse">Examples</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="viewport row">
       <div class="col-xs-12 view-animation" ng-view></div>
    </div>
```

---

css:

```
.ng-enter, .view-animation.ng-enter {
  left: 500px;
}

.ng-leave, .view-animation.ng-leave-active, .view-animation.ng-leave {
  left: -500px;
}
```

---

app.js:

```
var gulpNewy =
  angular
  .module('gulpNewy', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate'])
  .config(function($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider
          .when('/home', {
              templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
              controller: 'homeCtrl'
          })
          .when('/examples', {
              templateUrl: 'views/examples.html'
          })
      $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/home'});
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was the animation was happening to quick. Once I used

```
.view-animation {
  -webkit-transition: 1s;
}
```

I could see the animation.

Answer (score -1):

You need change class from controller. See https://www.google.com.ar/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.nganimate.org/&ved=0ahUKEwi_puevzonNAhXGlR4KHT-yApoQFggbMAE&usg=AFQjCNFuh3t3sGVMwBfRRh50fkenHFUpGw&sig2=9asfdX8gJs0msLmwyezNnA

Comment: I do not think that is correct. You would only change the class from the controller if you wanted custom animations based on the view. I am speaking of the same animation for all views. 

Reading the example in https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView#animations there is no changing of the class in the controllers.